# Add to a list of maps or update value of previously added map aws-dynamodb

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have a attribute of type 'List of maps' in my dynamodb. e.g. 
List = [{key1: value1},{key2: value2},{key3:value3},...]
I want to update the list (from my python script) with current_key to add a new key or replace the value if the current_key is already present.

Answer (score 0):

To illustrate the code below better, I've chosen to change your `{key1:value1}` to strings. Functionally, when you are calling the `add_to_datalist` function, there should be no difference.

```
def add_to_datalist(datalist, key, value):
    check = 0 
#check is needed to ensure the if condition after the for loop can trigger
    for datadict in datalist:
        if key in datadict.keys():
            datadict[key] = value
            check = 1 #turn off check if a key matching is found

    if check == 0:
        datalist.append({key:value})

    return datalist



datalist = [{'key1':'value1'},{'key2':'value2'},{'key3':'value3'}]

key1 = 'key333'
value1 = 'value999'
datalist = add_to_datalist(datalist, key1, value1)
key2 = 'key2'
value2 = 'valueNEW2'
datalist = add_to_datalist(datalist, key2, value2)

print (datalist)
#[{'key1': 'value1'}, {'key2': 'valueNEW2'}, {'key3': 'value3'}, {'key333': 'value999'}]
```

Comment: I want to update a row in amazon dynamodb. Need an update dynamodb query.

Comment: You can save `datalist` to a `values.json` file and make use of https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions.SET to update your dynamodb. I've already given you the python script to get the data in the correct format you require. The rest is how you configure your dynamodb because I do not know your settings